# How to create a sort button that sorts different divs [in table] in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, sorting, html-table

I have an HTML table with different `<td>` 's.
How do I sort these divs based on IMDb rating, TomatoMetre, etc...
[ CSS of the code is not included below ]

```html
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="column">
      <br>
      <div>
        <div>1<br></div>
        <div>
          <mark class="names">INTERSTELLAR</mark><br>
          <span><mark class="names">CHRISTOPHER NOLAN,2014</mark></span><br>
          <span><mark>US | Sci-Fi/Adventure</mark></span>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="rating">
          <p>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><img title="IMDB Rating" alt="IMDB" src="" class="imdb-img"></a>
            <a href=""><img title="Rotten Meter" alt="Rotten Tomatoes" src="" class="imdb-img"></a>
            <a href=""><img title="MetaScore" alt="MetaCritic" src="" class="imdb-img"></a>
            <img title="Audience Rating" alt="Google Rating" src="" class="imdb-img">
            <br>
            <span class="imdb-rate">8.6</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="imdb-rate">72%</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="imdb-rate">74%</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="imdb-rate">92%</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td class="column">
      <br>
      <div>
        <div>2<br></div>
        <div>
          <mark class="names">INTERN</mark><br>
          <span><mark class="names">CHRISTOPHER NOLAN,2014</mark></span><br>
          <span><mark>US | Sci-Fi/Adventure</mark></span>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="rating">
          <p>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><img title="IMDB Rating" alt="IMDB" src="" class="imdb-img"></a>
            <a href=""><img title="Rotten Meter" alt="Rotten Tomatoes" src="" class="imdb-img"></a>
            <a href=""><img title="MetaScore" alt="MetaCritic" src="" class="imdb-img"></a>
            <img title="Audience Rating" alt="Google Rating" src="" class="imdb-img">
            <br>
            <span class="imdb-rate">5.6</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="imdb-rate">70%</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="imdb-rate">54%</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="imdb-rate">91%</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

TLDR; There are so many cells with different IMDB , Tomatometre... Values. How to sort (Descending) these cells based on these values?

Comment: how your html is generated?

Comment: What Javascript have you tried so far?

Comment: I have'nt tried any javascript yet because i am too weak at js. I just need some basic js code for this :(

Comment: This isn't really a question about sorting table columns as there is scant use of CSS table - finding the structure of the data, such as it is, comes from doing detective work on the HTML and noticing that the different scores (there are 4, imdb, rotten tomatoes etc. can be winkled out by looking for things with class imdb-rate. Slightly yuk but it is structured enough so it can be done. You need to learn some basic JS like getting elements using query selectors.

Comment: I agree with @AHaworth. You will need to know at least a beginner amount of querySelecting and dom manipulation for this to work. Bootstrap and other resources have prebuilt sortable tables, but those have a learning curve too. I think it would be easier to learn some js yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The main JS that you need for this is

1. a way of getting all the elements of a certain type/class - querySelectorAll
2. a way of sorting an array against some value/function - array.sort

Briefly, get all the rows in the table, for each row got through each of the columns remembering their ratings and then sorting on whichever rating is required.

Follow the comments in this code to see the details.

```js
// set this to which rating you want the columns to be sorted by 0=imdb, 1=tomatoes etc
let rating = 0;

// this gives you a collection of the table's rows
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('row');
let rowno, columnno; // used in loops for the current row and column numbers

// go through each row
for (rowno=0; rowno < rows.length; rowno++) {
  let row = rows[rowno];
  
// we will push the columns and their ratings onto this array
  let list = [];
  
// get all the columns (the table cells, the tds) for this row 
  let columns = row.querySelectorAll('td');
  
// go through all the columns
  for (columnno = 0; columnno < columns.length; columnno++) {
    let column = columns[columnno];
    let ratings = column.querySelectorAll('.imdb-rate'); //get the 4 ratings for this column
// remember the column (which is a td element) and its ratings
    list.push({'column': column, 'ratings': ratings});
    }
  
// now we have all the ratings for all the columns on this row
// sort array by rating in descending order
  list.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.ratings[rating].innerHTML.replace('%', '') < b.ratings[rating].innerHTML.replace('%', '')) return 1;
    if (a.ratings[rating].innerHTML.replace('%', '') > b.ratings[rating].innerHTML.replace('%', '')) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

// now we can rewrite the contents of the current row
  for (columnno = 0; columnno < list.length; columnno++) {
    row.append(list[columnno].column);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="column">
      <br>
      <div>
        <div>1<br></div>
        <div>
          <mark class="names">INTERSTELLAR</mark><br>
          <span><mark class="names">CHRISTOPHER NOLAN,2014</mark></span><br>
          <span><mark>US | Sci-Fi/Adventure</mark></span>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="rating">
          <p>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><img title="IMDB Rating" alt="IMDB" src="" class="imdb-img"></a>
            <a href=""><img title="Rotten Meter" alt="Rotten Tomatoes" src="" class="imdb-img"></a>
            <a href=""><img title="MetaScore" alt="MetaCritic" src="" class="imdb-img"></a>
            <img title="Audience Rating" alt="Google Rating" src="" class="imdb-img">
            <br>
            <span class="imdb-rate">8.6</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="imdb-rate">72%</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="imdb-rate">74%</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="imdb-rate">92%</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td class="column">
      <br>
      <div>
        <div>2<br></div>
        <div>
          <mark class="names">INTERN</mark><br>
          <span><mark class="names">CHRISTOPHER NOLAN,2014</mark></span><br>
          <span><mark>US | Sci-Fi/Adventure</mark></span>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="rating">
          <p>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><img title="IMDB Rating" alt="IMDB" src="" class="imdb-img"></a>
            <a href=""><img title="Rotten Meter" alt="Rotten Tomatoes" src="" class="imdb-img"></a>
            <a href=""><img title="MetaScore" alt="MetaCritic" src="" class="imdb-img"></a>
            <img title="Audience Rating" alt="Google Rating" src="" class="imdb-img">
            <br>
            <span class="imdb-rate">5.6</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="imdb-rate">70%</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="imdb-rate">54%</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="imdb-rate">91%</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```